# centroid function works only in console

Tags: d3.js

I try to draw lines which  theirs starting points have the arc's center coordinates. I used the function arc.centroid(d). But returned values are displayed only in the console with "console.log" and an error message showing that Uncaught ReferenceError: x1 is not defined . I need your Helps please.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
             <head>
         <h1>  test </h1>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> 

        </head>
       <body>
     <script>


     var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];
      var pie = d3.layout.pie();
       pie(dataset);
     var w = 300;
      var h = 300;
         var outerRadius = w / 2;
     var innerRadius = w/3;
     var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);


   var color = d3.scale.category10();

   //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
     //Set up groups
     var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
          .data(pie(dataset))
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + ", " + outerRadius + ")");
     //Draw arc paths
     arcs.append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
           return color(i);
       })
        .attr("d", arc);
     //text 
   arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
         })
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
          });
         // line 

          var linesAttributes = arcs.selectAll("line")
                      .data(pie(dataset))
                      .enter()
                      .append("svg:line")

                      .attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d);

                                              var b = arc.centroid(d)[0];
                                             var c = arc.centroid(d)[1];

                                               console.log(b);

                                                  return arc.centroid(d)[0];})
                      .attr("y1", function(d) { console.log(d);
                                                     var b = arc.centroid(d)[0];
                                             var c = arc.centroid(d)[1];


                                               console.log(c);
                                                  return c;}
                                             )
                      .attr("x2", function(d,i) { return x1 + 100 ;}) 
                      .attr("y2", function(d,i) { return y1 + 100;}) 
                      .attr("class", "line") 

                      .style("stroke", function (d) {return color(d.data) ; })
                      .style("stroke-width", "3px");



                             </script>
                               </body>
                             </html>
```

---

The result of the console was the coordinates of each center  of pie's arcs and an error message showing that x1 is not defined! Why it's not defined if its value was showed !!!

Object {data: 25, value: 25, startAngle: 2.547237286694427, endAngle: 3.962369112635775} 
124.19981595246274 
Object {data: 6, value: 6, startAngle: 5.660527303765393, endAngle: 6.000158941991317} 
-112.4009018619796 
......
Uncaught ReferenceError: x1 is not defined LastEssay.html:76

Comment: `x1` is certainly not defined in the code you're showing. Where do you think you're defining it?

Comment: here .attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d);

                                              var b = arc.centroid(d)[0];
                                             var c = arc.centroid(d)[1];

                                               console.log(b);

                                                  return arc.centroid(d)[0];}) with the return

Comment: That statement adds an attribute to an SVG element in the DOM. It does not define a JavaScript variable. You should probably look into some basic JavaScript tutorials before trying to use D3.js.

Comment: ok thanks a lot Stephen Thomas :)